# Return DataTable within Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm fairly new to web services so please be gentle.

My current problem is that I'm trying to update 2 systems with job updates (lets call them system A and system B). In the process I need to record the result of the update (success or failure). These results need to be put into a database table (MyUpdateLog).

To make it a little trickier the updates that need to update system A have a 3 stage process to making it a successful update. Only stage 1 will access the web service. It's at this stage I need to return the success or failure of the first stage update. A datatable is passed to the web service with all updates to be made. Each update is then attempted individually through the web service. Initially I thought I would simply call a stored procedure to record the results in MyUpdateLog but this could end up with duplications.

In terms of capturing the result I figured an easy way would be to create a datatable (MyResults) within the web service, have a try / catch around the method call for processing the update, and update MyResults with the simple success or failure result for each job update.

NOTE: I'm not trying to return actual data from the database, but just the result of attempting to update the database.

The web service already exists and has an interface like this (I've added my DataTable with an operation contract):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataTable MyResults(DataTable updates);
}
```

The class using the interface is as follows (with my new method):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConCurrencyMode = ConCurrencyMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public DataTable MyResults(DataTable updates)
    {
        DataTable dtresults = new DataTable("My Results");
        dtresults.Columns.Add("Update ID", typeof(string));
        dtresults.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));
        string result = "";

        foreach(DataRow row in updates.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessUpdate(row["Update"].ToString());
                result = "Success";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Failed: " + ex.Message;
            }

            DataRow rwResults = dtresults.NewRow();
            rwResults["Update ID"] = row["ID"].ToString();
            rwResults["Result"] = result;
            dtresults.Rows.Add(rwResults);
        }
        return dtresults;
    }
}
```

So basically, is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: This is a bad idea that was discarded about a decade ago. For starters, the serialized document will be unreadable by non-.NET clients and the schema will be horrendous. Web services use schemas and you are trying to return essentially a schema-less object. If you want to return schema-less data, it would be far easier to use a REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is it just DataTable that's not workable in a web service? I thought this was something added in. What about DataSet? Just to update this will only need to work on a .NET client.